# Display only creator's files - Django/Python

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I would like to display only the pictures uploaded by the creator (user) on their individual profiles.

How would I alter my code to display that?

Thank you!

***models.py:***

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", default=1, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/photos/', null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'category')
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.creator)

    def get_image_url(self):
        return "%s/%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "%s/%s" %(self.creator, self.slug)
```

***views.py:***

```
@login_required
def account_home(request, username):
    try:
        u = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        u = None
    photo_set = Photo.objects.all()
    context = {
        "photo_set": photo_set,
        "notifications": notifications,
        "transactions": transactions
    }

    return render(request, "accounts/account_home.html", context)
```

***.html:***

```
{% for photo in photo_set %}
    <a href="{{ photo.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ photo.get_image_url }}" class='img-responsive'></a>
    <hr/>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a ForeignKey to user, so you can just filter the photos by that:

```
photo_set = Photo.objects.filter(creator=u)
```

or even better use the reverse relationship:

```
photo_set = u.photo_set.all()
```

Also, never ever ever ever use a blank `except` statement in your code. The only exception you are expecting the `get` to raise is `MyUser.DoesNotExist`, so you should catch that only.